# How to handle the case of multiple ground truth boxes having high IOU with the same predicted box?

Tags: neural-network, computer-vision

In [single shot detector](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.02325.pdf) the matching strategy between ground truth and predicted box starts with the following step:

> For each ground truth box we are selecting from default boxes that vary over location, aspect ratio, and scale. We begin by matching each ground truth box to the default box with the best
> jaccard overlap

What if two or more ground truth box is matched to the same default box? Should some check exist to make sure that each default box is matched to at most one ground truth box?

Comment: When found, it is related to a confidence score.
There is an explanatory video that is quite clear (see at 14:00): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F-irLP2k3Dk

Answer (score 0):

There is a process called Non-Max Supression (NMS) that takes care of this. It works by taking choosing the object prediction with the highest IOU, then calculating the IoU of the highest object prediction with that of all other object predictions. If the IoU between the highest object prediction is higher than a certain threshold, then the prediction with the lower confidence is suppressed.